# Unable to establish communication to active mq through DD4T web application

Tags: dd4t, sites-9, caching

We have configured Tridion sites 9 deployers,upgraded DD4T web application with DD4T.Provider.Tridion9.CIL able to retrieve the content successfully.
Configured Active Mq, updated deployer and content services with the caching configuration.  I was able to verify cache invalidation logs in the deployer when I publish the page.

The issue is with the DD4T web application cache invalidation. I am trying to configure the web application to connect to Active Mq.  Imported all the required packages but cache agent is unable to subscribe to JMS provider.  Below is the code snippet on Application_start()

```
var cacheAgent = container.Resolve<ICacheAgent>();
var defaultCacheAgent = cacheAgent as DefaultCacheAgent;
 if (defaultCacheAgent is DefaultCacheAgent)
{
                messageProvider.Start();
                defaultCacheAgent.Subscribe(messageProvider);
}
```

On debugging found `cacheAgent` is an object of DD4T.Providers.DXAModelservice.Caching.DxaCacheAgent and unable to cast to `DefaultCacheAgent`, thus the condition is not satisfied and JMS is not subscribed.
Any leads to resolve this issue is appreciated.

Comment: another doubt is why its instantiating object for DXAModelservice.Caching.DxaCacheAgent instead of Tridion 9.CIL.  Does Tridion 9  CIL relies on DXAModelservice?  Pardon if I ask a naive question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Tridion StackExchange Swapna!

I guess that you’re currently using both `DD4T.Providers.DXAModelservice` and `DD4T.Providers.Tridion9.CIL` DLL's in your DD4T web app.

Remove the `DD4T.Providers.DxaModelService.dll` in your DD4T web app and try again.

**Question:** Does `DD4T.Providers.Tridion9.CIL` rely on DXAModelservice?

**Answer:** No, That’s “traditional”; It doesn’t use GraphQL and DXA Model service.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome!  Indeed there were DxaModelservice.dll(residual dlls)  in the webapp/bin folder even though I uninstall it from Nuget - causing the issue.  Removing them resolved issue.  Thanks for your help! Infact it was your article which I followed to configure Active Mq.  Thanks again!